# chrome's <model-viewer> Paused on promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, augmented-reality, model-viewer

I'm trying to assign the texture from a canvas(fabric.js) to model-viewer's baseColorTexture. But no luck. And the error is Paused on promise rejection. I need guidance. Thanks

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
const modelViewerTexture = document.querySelector('model-viewer');
modelViewerTexture.model.materials[0].pbrMetallicRoughness['baseColorTexture'].texture.source.setURI(img);
```

Comment: What error message displayed?

Comment: I got a similar message:
     'Paused on Promise Rejection
     Reference error: startPont is not defined'.
The message went away after I noticed an extra '}' at the end of my main function. Have no clue what a promise is.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution already

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas').toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0)
const modelViewerTexture = document.querySelector('model-viewer')

localStorage.setItem('imgData', can)
modelViewerTexture.model.materials[0].pbrMetallicRoughness['baseColorTexture'].texture.source.setURI(localStorage.getItem('imgData'))
```